What to do if inverse of Leontief matrix is filled with #DIV/0! error? MRIO analysis
I was doing IO table analysis with EORA26 database. When I try to get an inverse Leontief matrix, excel yields #DIV/0! error in the whole matrix. I think I am doing every step right. I checked the determinant of Leontief matrix and it again yields the same error.
I did the same analysis in R studio using leontief package. Once again, at the stage of leontief_inverse function, the matrix is filled with NaN.
Could you please tell me if anything is wrong with the data?

We can't do anything without a reproducible example ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Isn't this just to compute x = (I - A)^-1 * y for given matrix A and demand vector y?
